# How likely is it for the Lotto jackpot to be won in consecutive draws

Tags: probability

I've been pondering upon a little probability problem that needs a bit more maths mastery than I possess.

Basically what I want to know is how likely is it for the Lotto jackpot,any lottery, not just our UK one, to be won in consecutive draws. I know the probability of a player picking all 6 numbers in the UK game are just over 45m to 1, and I know how this is calculated, but is there a formal to calculate the odds of two random people, who have nothing in common other than being blessed with phenomenal luck, scooping the jackpot sequential draws? I would imagine it's far less likely to win if the jackpot has just been won, some people only play once a week and some only when there's a humongous sum of money at stake, so when there are fewer entries then obviously there's less of a chance a matching combination will be in the pool. But would there be a way to calculate how much the odds of winning are diminished by playing in a draw immediately after someone has won?

Cheers

Comment: You need to know or estimate how many entries there are on average and in the week following a jackpot, and possibly also the distribution of entries (which you might estimate from how often people share jackpots)

Comment: There is no way to avoid playing the combinations of other people to share the jackpot with as few people as possible although some people successfully claim to have such a system and advertise it. Many people use dates or patterns, so it might be wise to avoid such combinations.

Comment: However, the probability to win is independent from what happened in the past. So, you always have your 45m:1 chance (for each combination) no matter whether someone has just cracked the jackpot or not.